Can I live stream my xfiniity webcam to my wordpress site?
There are a number of unknowns here because I don't actually have access to the xfinity account at the moment.
But the context is that I board my horse at a barn where the owner recently got xfinity internet installed. Part of the deal was a webcam, and she set it up to monitor all the horses' stalls by mounting it up high facing down the aisle, with 11 horse stalls in view.
She can login to her xfinity account and watch the live video feed on her phone. But the boarders can't view it because she doesn't want to share the account credentials with the boarders.
I've just set up a members-only WordPress site for her so that she can post information for the boarders. I know that there exist a number of WordPress plugins that support live streaming content, but don't understand how they operate (or how live streaming works) well enough to imagine if this would be possible. But what I'd like to do would be to embed the login credentials within a shortcode I would write, so that nobody would be able to see the login information. And the shortcode would then login to the xfinity account and stream the video to the page where it was used. Or if xfinity limits the number of logins to the account, then somehow put the login within a one-time initialization procedure, and make the stream viewable to all the logged-in users on the members-only site, which would have no more than a dozen or two members.
Does that make sense, and would it be possible?
